# SQL server field naming conventions

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a database that has 50 tables and all the tables have primary key on a field named ID. For example, Employee.ID, Customer.ID, order.ID, every single table has ID as its primary key. Should it not be Employee.Employee_ID, Customer.Customer_ID and so on?

Is there any drawback of using ID as name of every ID field in each table? If so please explain or give link to explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use **Employee.Id** and **Customer.Id** with the qualifying table names.  *Employee.EmployeeId* and *Customer.CustomerId* seem a bit redundant to me.

Comment: I would, however, have a naming convention that uses the name for foreign references (e.g. customer_Id, employee_Id) in other tables.

Comment: so when it comes to foreign key, u want to put employeeID and CustomerID in other tables dont u?

Comment: Agree 100% with Joe - e.g. Order.CustomerId for a foreign key.

Comment: i use empFK and custFK in related tables

Comment: Given the number of times I've found out that the `id` column was *not* designed to be the primary key, I prefer to be explicit.  Less likely to screw up joins too.

Answer (score 2):

There are different schools of thought on this.  Personally, I prefer to use identical column names only for columns that have primary key / foreign key relationships -- it helps make it easier to write complex joins.

Also, the apparent redundancy disappears when you use table aliases.  For example:

```
SELECT o.OrderDate, c.CustomerName
    FROM Customers c
    INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1):

It's largely a matter of personal style.

However, if your queries always use appropriate aliases for your tables, and you always use aliases when referencing columns, then it's not too bad.

Please don't fall into the habit (as many do) of saying "There's only one `Customer_EmployeeID` field in my query, so I'll leave off the alias". It's really ordinary, and drives SQL people crazy when they look at code that's done this way (you end up wanting to query sys.columns to see which table contains a column called `latest_status`).

So if you're writing your queries nicely, it shouldn't really matter how you name your columns, so long as you're consistent. Using a plain old "ID" for any integer identity field is just fine, so long as that's what you always do.

Answer (score 0):

I typically follow the same naming conventions (Entity.Id rather than Entity.EntityId).

If you think of your tables as entities, adding the table name to the ID field is redundant, forces you to write more code, and makes your queries harder to read.